# Dependency error while installing SimplebarAngular module in Angular 12 project

Tags: angular, simplebar

I have created an Angular project. The version is 12.
[image]

Now I would like to install **[SimplebarAngular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplebar-angular)** by npm command in my project. But after pressing the

> npm install simplebar-angular --save

command, I get the below error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve the error and install the angular module.

Comment: It seems that package is only suitable for angular 8.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SimplebarAngular** requires Angular legacy-peer-deps=true
, but you have Angular **12.x**. If you would like to ignore these issues - just follow instructions from the error:

- use `npm install simplebar-angular --save --force`
- use `npm install simplebar-angular --save --legacy-peer-deps`
- or you could add `.npmrc` to the project root to always apply `legacy-peer-deps`:

  legacy-peer-deps=true